# Actionbarsherlock Main SherlockFragmentActivity ClassNotFoundException

Tags: intellij-idea, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, classnotfoundexception

I have added Actionbarsherlock 4.3.1 to an existing project in IntelliJ. With some dificulties to begin with. There are no errors and the app compiles, but i am getting a runtime error on startup and the app crashes.

My Main Screen now extends SherlockFragmentActivity, before ABS i had FragmentActivity and everything was working fine. I changed all the Fragments to SherlockFragments and am getting no errors as mentioned. this is my error log. What am i missing?

```
07-08 13:31:37.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.adix.Gesetze/com.adix.Gesetze.MainScreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adix.Gesetze.MainScreen
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adix.Gesetze.MainScreen
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
```

Am happy to provide additional info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by changing the scope of the support library to compile. I had it on provide when i was trying arround with a other issue i had with ABS 4.3.1